# Freestyle marked edge being doubled up

Tags: freestyle

I'm trying to build up a library of sets and props in Blender so I can use them as backgrounds for drawings, so after discovering Freestyle I'm trying to replicate the line style in that (and also exploring what else I can get Blender to do for me, but that's another subject).

For my first project I made a bed as that seemed simple enough.  The end result is looking fairly good but the absence of a line on the mattress is hurting the final result.

[image: Test render]

I discovered you could mark edges as Freestyle edges and I thought that doing that would fix the issue, so I added a mark on the mattress model.

[image: Marked edge]

But instead Freestyle added 2 lines to the output: The one I wanted and another one parallel to it.

[image: Test render 2]

Can anybody help explain what might be going on with this?  This is the .blend for the asset in question.

[image]

EDIT: I did discover that one of the bed's components was inside out.  I recalculated the normals on that part, but that didn't resolve the issue.